# How can I retrieve my Canadian eTA?

Tags: canada, eta

I have a Canadian eTA (Electronic Travel Authorization) for the last 11 months (I'm working in BC on a Work Permit).
Up to now, showing my passport at check-in was enough, as all airlines could retrieve the eTA that is linked to my Passport.

However, on a recent check-in (ANA in Bangkok), I was asked for my eTA.

I searched various URLs found via Google, but none allowed me to retrieve my eTA.

Do you know a URL from which I can get my Canadian eTA?

http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp
http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/index-featured-can.asp
https://www.canadaetavisa.com/faq/

### Edit 1:

Seems that the Canadian government *does not have the option* (as of October 2018) to retrieve your eTA off the Internet.
Thus, when you receive your eTA application approval email, **be sure to save it** (it contains: Status, Name, Passport number, eTA number, and Expiration date).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I used before, but I was in Canada only for tourist purposes: https://onlineservices-servicesenligne.cic.gc.ca/eta/applicationQuery?lang=en

Comment: Unfortunately, I recorded neither the _issue_ nor the _expiry_ dates, so the URL you mentioned would not help me retrieve my eTA number (both exact data are required therein).

Comment: @boardrider: oh ok. It's not at all in your email? That's the only other way I can think of where your eTA might be...

Answer (score 1):

For my recent flights, I brought a printed copy of the eTA approval email which I had received shortly after the application. I cannot check it right now, but I am pretty sure it contains both my name and passport number.

I am not sure whether this is generally considered a valid proof of an approved eTA, but in my case it was sufficient.

Comment: Alas, had I had the foresight to save that email all those months ago, I wouldn't need to ask the question above :-(